# How to post to the controller?

Tags: c#, html, controller

I am trying to post data from web form to the controller in my asp.net application so that I can authenticate the credentials which the user has enterted.
My code for the web form looks like this at the bottom of this code  there is a submit button.

```
<form action="~/Controller" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Enter your details</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="name ">name  </label>
            <input type="text"  name="name" value=""/>
```

When I run the code and then press the submit button I get an error 405 which is because a HTTP method is not allowed. This is code I have in the controller file. Is the error because I have made a mistake in the web forms of its it because of a error in the controller file.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void MyAction(string telephone, string emailadress, string name ) 
    { 
     
    }
```

Comment: what is your controller class name ? you need to put like : `~/Controller/Action`

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag-helpers, like seen below. documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MyAction" method="post">
        <!-- Input and Submit elements -->
 </form>
```

Comment: Implementing that in my code has helped me avoid getting the error message so that was a good suggestion